# Complete function multiplyMagic() to multiply two elements

Tags: javascript

Complete function multiplyMagic() to multiply two elements.

The function should never return an error, irrespective of input passed 
and should return 1 in case 
of any kind of error or problem with input. 
Use default parameters for the same.

sample input : multiplyMagic(2,3)

output - 6

Comment: `let multiplyMagic = (x,y)=> -x*y;`

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple - use `*` for multiplication:

```js
function multiplyMagic(x, y) {
  return x * y || 1;
}

console.log(multiplyMagic(2, 3));
```

You can use ES6 to make it simpler as well:

```js
const multiplyMagic = (x, y) => x * y || 1;

console.log(multiplyMagic(2, 3));
```